# Movieclip -> BitmapData and origin

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm trying to draw a MovieClip to a BitmapData so that it looks exactly the same as if I had done addChild(movieclip).

I can't seem to figure out what magic formula I need to use to keep the animation in place around it's origin.

This is the relevant bit of code:

```
private function update(e:Event):void
{
    var bounds:Rectangle = movieClip.getBounds(movieClip);
    bitmapData = new BitmapData(maxMCwidth, maxMCheight, true, 0x0);
    bitmapData.draw(movieClip, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, maxMCwidth - (bounds.x + bounds.width), maxMCheight - (bounds.y + bounds.height)));
    bitmap.bitmapData = bitmapData;
}
```

Full code here: http://pastebin.com/KyU5FPeJ

And this is what the result looks like:

http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1339173476

The top animation is done using addChild(mc). The bottom animation is done using bitmapData.draw. Notice how the sword on the right doesn't move horizontally in the bottom version. Almost as if the whole animation was getting right-aligned.

Here's also a link to my flashdevelop project with the full code in case anybody wants to play around with it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvt4scknqdian2a/bitmapdatadrawing.zip

I just want both versions to look the same. What do I need to change to my bitmapData drawing code to make this happen?

Comment: What are you attempting to do with the Matrix? What is bounds? It looks to me like you are trying to scale it. I would start by using a default matrix and see if the "sword" gets the height like it should.

Comment: If you want to scale the image you should be changing the "a" and "d" values of the matrix not the "tx" and "tx" which you are doing here

Comment: I'm not changing the a & d values because I'm not trying to scale it. Thanks for helping but please see the question, nowhere do I mention scaling, I'm just trying to translate the animation so that it stays centered around the origin.

Comment: Without the matrix translation the animation is cut off: http://megaswf.com/file/2442112

Comment: Better link: http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1339173363

Comment: but notice in the new links provided the "sword" is behaving like it should. ( it goes high enough to be cut off completely now) Try not changing the matrix at all but just change the x/y of where ever you place the bitmapData.

Comment: How do you suggest I stop it from being cut off? That was my intention with the translation. My goal is to make it look just like the animation above it.

Comment: Not sure I understand. BitmapData doesn't have an x/y, I just update a bitmap with it like so `bitmap.bitmapData = bitmapData`

Comment: Yes it doesn't but the UIContainer you put it in will have x/y. If you look back at the first link posted in the question you will that the height is squished down on the bottom img. Somehow something is scaling the height. Let me see if i can dig up some code. I ran into something similar a few years back where I had to draw in a mask over parts of an image.

Comment: I tried changing the x/y of the container, which moves the animation to a new position but it still looks cut off. If you have a moment, I would be super ultra grateful if you could download my project and give it a try. I've been bashing my head against this problem all day without a resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out!

The cause of the problem was that I'm not calculating maxMCwidth or maxMCheight correctly. I was going through the movieclip looking for the widest/highest single frame. BUT that doesn't take into account that the position of bounds across frames changes. To get the actual maximum width/height across the whole animation, I used this code:

```
maxBounds = new Rectangle();
for (var i:uint = 0; i < movieClip.totalFrames; i++)
{
    var tempBounds:Rectangle = movieClip.getBounds(movieClip);
    maxBounds = maxBounds.union(tempBounds); 
    movieClip.nextFrame();
}
```

Then this allowed me to fix the translation matrix:

```
bitmapData.draw(movieClip, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -maxBounds.x, -maxBounds.y));
```

And like this it works for every animation I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can't get your project to run since you didn't supply a main mxml.
However, I think I found your issue.
I don't think getBounds is returning the values you think they are.
I can't look into the skeleton swc but I have a feeling there is on object off the top or bottom of the screen in it and the way you coded it would cause it to shrink down to make it fit.
getBounds is probably adding that to the height.

```
bitmapData = new BitmapData(movieClip.width, movieClip.height, true, 0x0);
bitmapData.draw(movieClip, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, movieClip.width/2, movieClip.height/2 )); 
bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
bitmap.x = 70;
bitmap.y = 200;
```

Remember untested code here. :(